# Cloudfront Alternate Domain Names InvalidViewerCertificateException

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, certbot

My setup

- EC2: app
- Domain Registrar: namecheap
- DNS: route 53

I use EC2 to host my app, AWS route 53 to direct the url, and cloudfront to fetch the static files for my app. Right now the cloudfront is using unfriendly domain `*.cloudfront.net`.

I am using certbot inside my EC2 to provide SSL connection.

When I tried to change cloudfront domain name, I use the `Custom SSL Certificate` generate by ACM (AWS certificate manager). And I encountered the error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.InvalidViewerCertificateException: The certificate that is attached to your distribution doesn't cover the alternate domain name (CNAME) that you're trying to add. For more details, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-requirements (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidViewerCertificate; Request ID: 2d39c685-bf17-4d24-9c4b-82955daa878f; Proxy: null)
```

The ACM cert is generated in N.Virginia, which is fine since my EC2 is hosted there. I generated the cert using `*.example.com` and it is verified.

I am not sure how to fix that. Any advise?

Comment: Hi, can you provide additional information on the ACM certificate? Was it generated by ACM or uploaded by you? Is it single domain or multi domain?

Comment: @mokugo-devops It is generated by ACM. Single domain: `*.example.com`

Comment: OK and you're using a domain of *.example.com, not example.com?

Comment: That's right. Based on ACM: `Type the fully qualified domain name of the site you want to secure with an SSL/TLS certificate (for example, www.example.com). Use an asterisk (*) to request a wildcard certificate to protect several sites in the same domain. For example: *.example.com protects www.example.com, site.example.com and images.example.com.`

Comment: Hmm, that error is because it thinks the domain for the SSL does not match the domain you're using as a custom cloudfront domain name.

Comment: Does it mean that it has nothing to do with me with certbot's cert inside EC2? Which is different from ACM cert?

Comment: Since you issued ssl cert for `*.example.com`, what is the form of the domain name you want to use for your CF distribution (e.g. www.example.com)?

Comment: Hi, as this is viewer certificate it is the ACM certificate

Comment: Since it's ACM cert, I'm thinking that it should worked for all `*.example.com`? Such as `https://example.com` and `www.example.com`

Comment: No, it won;t work for https://example.com. For that you'd need an additional domain on the SSL

Comment: it will work only for `www.example.com`. If you use `example.com` it will not work.

Comment: @mokugo-devops Could you  provide an answer?  I think the issue has been found. Thank you.

Comment: Have done :) Glad its been resolved for you

Comment: @mokugo-devops Its not my issue, would have to wait for OP to confirm if its fully resolved. But this seems to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be caused by an invalid domain name being used for the ACM certificate you have provisioned.

Because the ACM certificate generated is *.example.com only a 1 level deep subdomain can be used.

To explain this further:

- www.example.com is a valid subdomain for the ACM certficate
- foo.bar.example.com is not a valid subdomain for the ACM certficate
- example.com is not valid for this ACM certficate as it is the root domain (and not referenced on the SSL).

Because it is generated in ACM, we can validate this certificate is compatiable as long as it meets the [following conditions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-invalid-viewer-certificate/).

For the SSL to work for the root domain and subdomain it must contain both example.com and *.example.com to work correctly within CloudFront.